# A second-order difference equation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Fix a positive integer $r\geq 2$. For each integer $k\geq 2$, we have the recursion
$$
\left(k + 2\right)\left(k + \frac{1}{3}\right)a_{k} - 2\left(k + 1\right)
\left(k - 1 + r\right)a_{k-1}
+ \left(k - 2 + r\right)\left(k - \frac{1}{3} + r\right)a_{k-2}
=
0
$$ Moreover, $a_{0} = 1$ and $a_{1} = r$. I have no experience whatsoever with difference equations. So I was wondering if I could get some advice or suggestions on finding a solution ( assuming it exists ).

Comment: Use a 'generating function': $\displaystyle{\large{\rm F}\left(z\right) \equiv \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}a_{k}z^{k}}$.

Comment: http://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/Slides/Generating-Functions.pdf